# How to fix Warning: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

**Warning**:  Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in **/home/conteud2/public_html/include/meta.php** on line **114**

variate code using {var2[id]} no solution

Code in on comment below

You can check the issue on page https://www.conteudoanimal.vet.br/racaseespecies/anfibios/ver.php?id=5

Server runs PHP7 at moment

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: <?php 
$variavel1 = strtolower($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$variavel2 = strtolower($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
parse_str($variavel2, $var2);
$opendes = '<meta name="description" content="';
echo $opendes;
switch ($variavel1) {
case "/racaseespecies/anfibios/ver.php":
If (!empty($var2[id])) {
$query = "select raca,id from anfibios where id=$var2[id]";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Could not execute query");}
else{
$query = "select raca,id from anfibios where arquivo='$var2[arquivo]'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Could not execute query");}

Comment: Please don't post your code in the comment area. Instead edit your original question.

Comment: if too many vars to care: error_reportig(0)

Answer (score 2):

So it basically means that id isn't a constant.
It either should be $id, or 'id', also the var2 should be $var2.

Try the following code:

```
"{$var2['id']}"
```

Or

```
"{$var2[$id]}"
```